# how to find document and include the documents on its' property of array of object ids in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this model:

```
const BoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    threads: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Thread'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_on', updatedAt: 'updated_on' },
    versionKey: false
  }
);
```

Using Board.find({}) returns this:

```
{
    "boards": [
        {
            "threads": [
                "5d6562cc84ce221848e18911"
            ],
            "_id": "5d6562af84ce221848e18910",
            "name": "shelajoyhuiso",
            "created_on": "2019-08-27T17:04:47.536Z",
            "updated_on": "2019-08-27T17:05:17.436Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm new in mongoose and I don't know what's proper way to make the threads property to be array of documents and not an id since it's an array of object id?

Comment: Use `Board.find().populate('threads')` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thank you! I was resolving with this and I thought it's ugly: const result = await Promise.all(
          boards.map(async board => {
            const threads = await Promise.all(
              board.threads.map(thId => Thread.findById(thId))
            );
            return { ...board._doc, threads };
          })
        );

Answer (score 0):

Before @Molda's comment, I was settling with this:

```
const result = await Promise.all(
  boards.map(async board => {
   const threads = await Promise.all( board.threads.map(thId => Thread.findById(thId)) 
  );
return { ...board._doc, threads }; }) );
```

For Future Readers, this is the right way:

```
await Board.find(
  {},
  null,
  { sort: '-createdAt', limit: 9, populate: 'threads' },
  async (error, boards) => {
    if (error) res.status(400).send(error);
    res.status(200).json({ boards });
  }
);
```